# How to get the conf port of a call with PJSIP?

Tags: pjsip

Using PJSIP, I'm trying to play a wave file trough SIP. I am able to do that, but with hardcoding the output port:

```
pjsua_conf_connect(pjsua_player_get_conf_port(player_id), 1);
```

This work well.

```
14:17:50.596   conference.c  .Port 2 (s.wav) transmitting to port 1 (sip:81@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
```

On my tests I know that the output port is 1, but on production I don't know the number of it.
And if I try to get it from the pjsua_call_info structure, I get a total another number.

The code to read the conf_port:

```
int play_file(pjsua_call_info *ci){
//Some code to create the file player
printf("*************Port is %d\n", ci->conf_slot);
```

And my output is this:

```
*************Port is 284260
```

The number is 284260 but I expect 1.

I hope I was clear. If anybody has an idea, or a track to solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to play a wave file using the pjsua player and then trying to conference the stream being played with a call.

You will have to use `pjsua_call_get_conf_port` to get the conf port of a call.

```
pj_str_t fName = pj_str("somefile.wav"); //give full path if it's in a different directory
pj_status_t status;
pjsua_player_id playerId;
status = pjsua_player_create(&fName,0,&playerId);
if(status != PJ_SUCCESS)
        return;

//To play on the default output device.
//If you wish to set a particular sound device, you can use the 'pjsua_set_snd_dev' function.
//Use 'pjsua_enum_aud_devs' to get a list of devices connected to your system.

pjsua_conf_connect(pjsua_player_get_conf_port(playerId),0);

//To play on a ongoing call with the call id in variable 'callId'
pjsua_conf_connect(pjsua_player_get_conf_port(playerId),pjsua_call_get_conf_port(callId));
```

Comment: I tried to put this code at my side but it is not working. Can you please share exactly what value should be passed? Or any further detail?

Comment: Can you please suggest me third person number, where should I pass it? Your help will save me